# sas unzip on x command not working as directory path has embedded spaces

Tags: sas

I have a situation where am using sas x command to unzip a folder and select only .sas files from the same and the below code is working fine as there are no embedded spaces in the directory path..

x "cd &egp_location";  --> current directory --&egp_location resolves to folder path with no embedded spaces.

x "unzip &egp_name *.sas " ;  --> with in the current directory &egp_name resolves a file name that need to be unzipped.

if there are embedded spaces the above lines of code is not working.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
x "unzip ""&egp_name"" *.sas " ;
```

The double double quotes resolve to a single double quote character.

This assumes the unzip statement is otherwise valid - if you run

```
options mprint symbolgen;
```

you will get the full unzip statement in your log - copy/paste that to the console and see if it works.  If not, debug that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
x cd %STR(%")&egp_location%STR(%");
x unzip %STR(%")&egp_name%STR(%") *.sas;
```

I'm not sure of the syntax of the unzip command, but the %STR bits will add quotes around the macro variables.

Also, double quotes are not required around the whole command when using the X statement in SAS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Tried with above code, but the &egp_location is getting resolved twice. Like

if egp_location =\fjdkfjdkj\fdkfjdkfjd\fjdkfjd kfjdkfjdkj fdjfkdj.egp it is getting resolved as.. '"\fjdkfjdkj\fdkfjdkfjd\fjdkfjd kfjdkfjdkj fdjfkdj.egp\fjdkfjdkj\fdkfjdkfjd\fjdkfjd kfjdkfjdkj fdjfkdj.egp '"

leading to an error, such directory not available.

Comment: The code I posted should not resolve &egp_location twice. What is the **exact** value of this macro variable?

Comment: here is the log message - SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable EGP_LOCATION resolves to /abc/defg/hi/dev/userid/sas_mig/sas_hhhh/abc defgh cysd - x waves - fdfdfd ererere reresdf met email v2/                                                                               
ERROR: '/abc/defg/hi/dev/userid/sas_mig/sas_hhhh/abc defgh cysd - x waves - fdfdfd ererere reresdf met email v2/"/abc/defg/hi/dev/userid/sas_mig/sas_hhhh/abc defgh cysd - x waves - fdfdfd ererere reresdf met email v2/    
         "' : No such directory.

Comment: just to clarify.. to the text resolved from macro variable &egp_location a path pertaining to configuration folder is getting prefixed in this case '/fjdkfjd/GSR/bin1/SASConfigFolder/Lev2/SASAGUQ                 also the entire path getting closed in single quotes.                                                              sorry for any confusion.